# Sequelize: Where is an example of using bulkDelete with criteria?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write a seed file's `down` and I'd like to `bulkDelete` the data I created in my `up`.  But I can't find any documentation on how to do this.  The official docs don't give an example: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-bulkDelete

Can someone show me how to `bulkDelete` all rows in table `Foo` where `name` equals `x` or name equals `y`?

```
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Foo', [what do I put here?], {});
  }
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I tried using @Michael McCabe's suggestion and kept getting `ERROR: Invalid value [object Object]`. Once I got rid of `where` from the second argument (the identifier argument), I was able to get it working:

```
down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  const Op = Sequelize.Op
  return queryInterface.bulkDelete('users', {id: {[Op.in]: [2, 3]}}, {})
}
```

Comment: Fixed @MichaelMcCabe's answer so it's correct, since it was already accepted.  Thanks for catching that. (Not sure if that was the right way to correct this, but seemed the simplest.  Sorry you don't get more credit for it.)

Answer (score 20):

```
down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  const Op = Sequelize.Op; 

  return queryInterface.bulkDelete(
    'Foo',
    {[Op.or]: [{name: x}, {name: y}]}
  );
}
```

1st arg is the table name, 2nd arg is the `where` value that indicates which rows to delete.

Comment: Thank you, where did you learn how to do that?  Is that documented elsewhere?

Comment: In this case, the docs stated that the second argument contained the where conditions. Then its a usual sequelize where object. The `or` operator is shown with example in the list of operators in the docs [see operators here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators). I'll do a PR to update the docs to give an example for bulkDelete for others in the future

Comment: @DanielKaplan if this answered your question, can you please accept the answer

Comment: @MichaelMcCabe Edited your answer to reflect kaszac's comments, which I verified to be correct.  'Hope that's okay. (Also, please be a bit more diligent in verifying your answers actually work as expected. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the other two answers here worked for me. I stumbled upon the following answer though in a Sequelize GitHub issues discussion, which worked fine:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5615#issuecomment-248384147

Note that 'keyword' is the column name and 'Flags' is the table name:

```
down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Flags', {
        keyword: [
            "groupRegistration",
            "memberRegistration",
            "exhibitorRegistration",
            "facilitatorRegistration",
            "volunteerRegistration",
            "workshopSignup"
        ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Sequelize v6 they have a [shorthand](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#shorthand-syntax-for-opin) for `Op.in` operator.

```js
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    id: [1,2,3] // Same as using `id: { [Op.in]: [1,2,3] }`
  }
});
// SELECT ... FROM "posts" AS "post" WHERE "post"."id" IN (1, 2, 3);
```